# Why does PyQt5 QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory fail to see ~/.config/subdirectory?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyqt5

Under Python2.7 and PySide, I was able to point to subdirectories of ~/.config/. However, when I moved to Python3 and PyQt5, I can open to ~/.config/ but not to subdirectories of it... (All of the directories have `drwxr-xr-x` permissions and no special chattr stuff or ACL stuff happening.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Arch Linux (up-to-date)
# Python 3.6.5
# python-pyqt5 5.10.1-3

import os
import sys
from   PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from   PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from   PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Succeeds. (Lists three files in the autostart directory.)
wd = os.path.expanduser("~/.config/autostart")
os.system("ls {0}".format(wd))

# Fails. Opens to ~/
x = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption="Choose presets...", directory=wd)

wd = os.path.expanduser("~/.config")

# Succeeds. Opens at ~/.config/
x = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption="Choose presets...", directory=wd)

# Succeeds. Opens at ~/Documents/Volunteer
wd = os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/Volunteer")
x = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Choose presets...", wd)
```

Comment: I have no problems, and I am using Arch Linux with the same software versions, you could explain yourself better, maybe I have not understood you correctly.

Comment: @Ubuntourist . Try replacing all `"~/.config"` with the full path → `/home/name/.config` .... Not all OS, not all programs can use `~/` as a path.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem on arch linux (python 3.6.5, qt 5.11.0, pyqt 5.10.1). What DM are you using? Does it make any difference if you add `options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog` to the arguments?

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm using KDE. I'll try the options="..."

Comment: @KnudLarsen That's not it. The value that gets passed to the QFileDialog has already been expanded to the full path. That's what os.path.expanduser() does, and the fact that it succeeds in part of the code indicates the "~/" isn't the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, thanks to @ekhumoro we have a winner!  Telling the QFileDialog not to use the native dialog did the trick. Specifically:

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Arch Linux (up-to-date)
# Python 3.6.5
# python-pyqt5 5.10.1-3

import os
import sys
from   PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from   PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from   PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Succeeds. (Lists three files in the autostart directory.)
wd = os.path.expanduser("~/.config/autostart")
os.system("ls {0}".format(wd))

# SUCCEEDS (where it previously failed)
x = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption="Choose presets...", directory=wd,
                                     options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```

Comment: Well, it's great that it worked - but still pretty baffling. Is it only that directory that's affected? Or is it any dotted-path?

Comment: It behaves that way with all .dotted directories. However, using "pipenv shell", even though it claims to use the same version of PyQt5, the error does not occur... (Well, 5.10.1. "pip list" does not include the "-3".)